# Why does printing a pointer in %ld in C yield this result?

Tags: c

Why does printing a pointer in %ld in C yield this result?

```
 char txt[] = "abcdefghij";
 char *pointer = &txt[1];

 printf("%ld\n", pointer - txt);
 printf("%d\n", pointer - txt);
```

Both of these print 1, because its always subtracting big numbers by a difference of 1,
e.g. 3032 - 3031 .
But why do I get these numbers?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Using the incorrect format specifier is not going to end well.

Comment: @LuXxenatorX yes,, you can.  Similarly, I can drive my car off a cliff.

Comment: @DeiDei Why is the subtraction undefined? I'm a bit surprised. Are `char[]` and `char*` unrelated types?

Comment: Because you're unlucky. The type of the expression is not compatible with `"%ld"` or `"%d"`. You need to cast the value: `printf("%d", (int)(pointer - txt));`

Comment: It's strange though, because I can printf("%ld " , pointer); and printf("%ld", txt); and they both result in big values that are different by one number!

Comment: @Codor This particular subtraction yields a ptrdiff_t result. There is no guarantee that the underlying type is compatible with %d or %ld.

Comment: @DeiDei Thanks for the explanation - just out of curiosity, but the subtraction itself is (at least type-wise) _not_ undefined, I assume?

Comment: @LuXxenatorX: So, what is this question about? You know that the addresses are different by 1. You are printing it incorrectly, but the result is 1 and you know it. What is the question then?

Comment: @Codor Yes, of course, it's merely the printing of it. See Bathsheba's answer.

Comment: Are you asking why the result is 1, or why `pointer` and `txt` are the values they are?

Comment: @AnT Because I am printing an address, how does this translate into the resulting number? I am requesting a %ld, so is the hexadecimal transformed into that format?

Comment: @John Bode Both! but I anderstand the first , the latter I still dont

Comment: You are not printing an address, you are printing the difference between 2 addresses. It's very different! And the value of those addresses is basically random (or, to be precise: the first one is random, the second one isn't).

Comment: @LuXxenatorX: You are NOT printing an address. You are printing a *difference* between two addresses (result of *subtarction* of two addresses). In C this is always an *integer*.

Comment: @AnT: I thought the 1 represents undefined behavior?

Comment: The undefined behaviour in the code you show arises from printing a pointer-difference using a conversion specifier for `int`, that is `d`. To print a pointer difference use the conversion specifier `t`.

Comment: @LuXxenatorX: Undefined behavior is triggered by the way you attempt to *print* that 1. But the 1 itself is perfectly defined.

Comment: You're not printing a pointer; you're printing an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtracting two pointers to the same object is allowed by the C standard:

From [section 6.5.6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *9* When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the same array object**, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements.** The size of the result is implementation-defined, and
>   its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the
>   `stddef.h` header. If the result is not representable in an object of
>   that type, the behavior is undefined. In other words, if the
>   expressions P and Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements
>   of an array object, the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i−j provided
>   the value fits in an object of type ptrdiff_t. Moreover, if the
>   expression P points either to an element of an array object or one
>   past the last element of an array object, and the expression Q points
>   to the last element of the same array object, the expression
>   ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)),
>   and has the value zero if the expression P points one past the last
>   element of the array object, even though the expression (Q)+1 does not
>   point to an element of the array object.

When you evaluate `pointer - txt`, the array `txt` decays to a pointer to the first element, i.e. `&txt[0]`.  And since `pointer` points to `txt[1]`, you effectively have `&txt[1] - &txt[0]`.  As described above, the result of the subtraction is the difference between the subscripts, which is 1.

As for displaying this result properly, the `%d` and `%ld` format specifiers to `printf` are not appropriate for a `ptrdiff_t`, which is the type of the result.  As stated above, the size of this type is implementation defined.  Using the wrong format specifier to `printf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So you need to use the `t` modifier, which tells `printf` the given integer argument is of type `ptrdiff_t`:

```
printf("%td\n", pointer - txt);
```

Comment: So the 1 represents undefined behavior, not the actual result 1? So using %ld coincidentally results as if I had used %td?

Comment: @LuXxenatorX Correct.  You were "lucky" that the correct result happened to be printed.

Comment: Greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `%td` format might not be supported by some older implementations. To allow for that, you can cast to some known type. As for undefined behavior, you're printing an integer value with a format for a different integer type. That's likely to "work" if the types happen to have the same size, and depending on the system might even "work" if they have different sizes. The `1` is not a coincidence, just a result of the fact that working "correctly" is one possible consequence of undefined behavior.

Comment: This was the final bit of information I needed. Now I fully understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The way the pointers are initialized, `pointer` will point to one position after `txt`, which means that the difference is `1` due to pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

First note that you can only take the difference between two pointers if they are both in the same array, or one past the end of the array. Else the behaviour is *undefined*. You are compliant on this point.

But you are *not* compliant with your choice of format specifier. So the behaviour of your program is *undefined*. Really, I'd like to see

```
ptrdiff_t c = pointer - txt;
```

followed by

```
printf("%td\n", c);
```

`ptrdiff_t` is the *perfect* type for a difference between two pointers, and `%td` is the correct format specifier for that type. This is perfect portable C (if I may say so myself).

Comment: C language does not support pointer arithmetic for `void *` pointers. Your example with casts to `void *` is invalid.

Comment: Wow. You learn something new every day. I've *always* done it like this since I was a wee nipper. Perhaps it was from the old days where void* was essentially a char*?  I'll change it on blind trust for now, and have a look.

Comment: In the old days `void *` simply din not exist. It was introduced as something distinctively different from `char *` with no support for pointer arithmetic. Treating it as something equvalent to `char *` is actually a modern thing: a modern GCC extension.

Answer (score 0):

> But why do I get these numbers?

Just for reference, I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dumper.h"

int main( void )
{
  char txt[] = "abcdefghij";
  char *ptr = &txt[1];

  char *names[] = {"txt", "ptr"};
  void *addrs[] = {txt, &ptr};
  size_t sizes[] = {sizeof txt, sizeof ptr};

  /**
   * Use %p to print out pointer values.  %p expects the corresponding
   * argument to have type `void *`.  Because of how printf works,  
   * this is one of the few places were you really do need to explicitly
   * cast pointer values to `void *` (if they aren't already `void *`)
   */
  printf( "txt = %p\n", (void *) txt );
  printf( "ptr = %p\n", (void *) ptr );

  /**
   * Use %td to print out ptrdiff_t values.
   */
  printf( "ptr - txt = %td\n", ptr - txt );
  putchar( '\n' );

  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 2, stdout );

  return 0;
}
```

`dumper` is a utility I wrote to display the layout of objects in memory.  Running this code, I get the following output:

```
txt = 0x7fff7f137380
ptr = 0x7fff7f137381
ptr - txt = 1

           Item         Address   00   01   02   03
           ----         -------   --   --   --   --
            txt  0x7fff7f137380   61   62   63   64    abcd
                 0x7fff7f137384   65   66   67   68    efgh
                 0x7fff7f137388   69   6a   00   00    ij..

            ptr  0x7fff7f137378   81   73   13   7f    .s..
                 0x7fff7f13737c   ff   7f   00   00    ....
```

`txt` is an 11-element array of `char` stored starting at address `0x7fff7f137380` and contains the sequence of `char` values `"abcdefghij\0"`.  `ptr` is a pointer to `char` stored starting at address `0x7fff7f137378`, and it stores the address of `txt[1]` (`0x7fff7f113781`) (x86 is little-endian, so multi-byte values are stored starting with the least-significant byte).

But wait, if `txt` is an *array*, how can it be subtracted from a *pointer*?

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the expression `ptr - txt`, `txt` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and it isn't a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, so it "decays" from an expression of type "11-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and its value is the address of `txt[0]`.

Okay.  Why such huge numbers for the addresses of `txt` and `ptr`?  Under x86 and x86-64, program layout looks something like this:

```
              +-----------------------------+
High Address: |   Command-line arguments    |
              |  and environment variables  |
              +-----------------------------+
              |            Stack            |
              |              |              |
              |              V              |
              |                             |
              |              ^              |
              |              |              |
              |            Heap             |
              +-----------------------------+
              |     Uninitialized Data      |
              +-----------------------------+
              |      Initialized Data       |
              +-----------------------------+
              |        Program Text         |
 Low Address: |       (machine code)        |
              +-----------------------------+
```

Both `txt` and `ptr` are `auto` variables, which on x86 means space for them is allocated from the stack, which starts at a high address.  On my system, pointers are 64 bits wide.

Now, in this case it's true that the addresses of `txt[0]` and `txt[1]` differ by 1.  But let's try something - let's change the type of `txt` to `int []` and `ptr` to `int *`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dumper.h"

int main( void )
{
  int txt[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  int *ptr = &txt[1];

  char *names[] = {"txt", "ptr"};
  void *addrs[] = {txt, &ptr};
  size_t sizes[] = {sizeof txt, sizeof ptr};

  printf( "txt = %p\n", (void *) txt );
  printf( "ptr = %p\n", (void *) ptr );

  printf( "ptr - txt = %td\n", ptr - txt );
  putchar( '\n' );

  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 2, stdout );

  return 0;
}
```

Running this, I get the following output:

```
txt = 0x7fff317fa850
ptr = 0x7fff317fa854
ptr - txt = 1

           Item         Address   00   01   02   03
           ----         -------   --   --   --   --
            txt  0x7fff317fa850   00   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa854   01   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa858   02   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa85c   03   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa860   04   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa864   05   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa868   06   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa86c   07   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa870   08   00   00   00    ....
                 0x7fff317fa874   09   00   00   00    ....

            ptr  0x7fff317fa848   54   a8   7f   31    T..1
                 0x7fff317fa84c   ff   7f   00   00    ....
```

The difference in the addresses of `txt` and `ptr` is 4, but `ptr - txt` still yields 1.  Why is that?

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to object into account - if `p` is a pointer to `T`, then `p + 1` yields the address of the next *object of type `T`*, not the address of the next byte.  `&txt[n] - &txt[n-1]` will **always yield 1**, regardless of whether each `txt[n]` is 1, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 128 bytes wide.